# Drawing a Cayley table given a binary operation - not sure how to proceed

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cayley-table

> Let $Y=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ and let $\cup: Y\times Y\to Y$ be a binary operation.
>
> a) Draw the following table in your answer book, then complete the table for the binary operation $\cup:Y\times Y\to Y$.   (Note that $\cup$ is the existing set union operation.   It is *not* an operation that you may arbitrarily define.)
>
> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline \bigcup & \emptyset & \{\emptyset\} \\ \hline \emptyset \\ \hline \{\emptyset\} \\ \hline \end{array}$$

[image]

Please advise on the steps for answering a question like this.

So far, I assume that the first step would be to determine Y x Y.

Not sure how to proceed thereafter. Do I need to put something in list notation? Seems a bit too lengthy for 4 marks.

[The question is from a past exam of an introductory computer science module]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cup : Y\times Y\to Y$ means that: "$\cup$ is a function mapping arguments in $Y$ and $Y$ to a result in $Y$".

You're told that $\cup$ is the set union operator, and that $Y=\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$

---

Thus you need simply fill out the table.   For instance, $\varnothing \cup \varnothing = \varnothing$ so $\varnothing$ is what you put in the first row, first column entry.

Now complete the entries for $\;\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\}\;$, $\;\{\varnothing\}\cup\varnothing\;$, and $\;\{\varnothing\}\cup\{\varnothing\}\;$

---

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline \cup & \emptyset & \{\emptyset\} \\ \hline \emptyset & \emptyset \\ \hline \{\emptyset\} \\ \hline \end{array}$$

So four empty boxes, four four marks. I've don't one, you do the rest.

That is all.